# How to use type parameter within method declaration instead of class

Tags: java, generics

I have this code which work:

Interface:

```
public interface Queries<T> {
    List<User> runQuery(T query);
}
```

and using the interface:

```
public class UserQueries implements Queries<UserQuery> {

    @Override
    List<User> runQuery(UserQuery q){
    }
}
```

I want to replace the above with the following code, however, it does not work:

**New Interface:**

```
public interface Queries {
     // I want to pass the type parameter within the abstract method instead of the using Queries<T>
    <T> List<User> runQuery(T query);
}
```

**and using the new Interface (version 2):**

```
public class UserQueries implements Queries {

    // does not work, compiler complains:
    // "The method runQuery(UserQuery) of type UserQueries must override or implement a supertype method
    @Override
    List<User> runQuery(UserQuery q) {
    }
}
```

**How can I use type parameter `<T>` within method intead of class?**

Comment: Well, your first snippet did exactly what you wanted, so just go back to it. That's the proper way. If en interface defined a generic method, all the implementations of the interface must implement this *generic* method, in a *generic* way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mix 2 concepts one is generics and another is inheritance.

**Version 1** In version 1 you have generic interface

```
public interface Queries<T>
```

And in the implementation you are restricting it to accept `UserQuery` type

```
public class UserQueries implements Queries<UserQuery> {
```

**Version 2** In version 2 you have concrete interface with generic abstract method

```
public interface Queries {
 // I want to pass the type parameter within the abstract method instead of the using Queries<T>
<T> List<User> runQuery(T query);
}
```

So if you implement `Queries` interface then you have to provide implementations of all abstract methods (if you change the method signature or syntax of method, that method is considered as different method in class but not the abstract method in interface)

Comment: So when using version 2 with implementation of `<T> List<User> runQuery(T query){..}`, I have to downcast the generic manually to `UserQuery`. So it is better to use version 1. The one which forces me to change the class declaration of all Queries<T> in all the sources to the actual type, for example: Queries<UserQuery>.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to **Java's Type Erasures**. 
What is happening here is that after compilation this code `<T> List<User> runQuery(T query)` is changing to `List<User> runQuery(Object query)`. So that's why in child class you can't use the concrete implementation.

[For you reference: Type Erasures in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-erasure-java/)

Comment: That has nothing to do with type erasure. The code doesn't *compile*. Simply because the class doesn't implement the interface.

Comment: Yes you are right but due to type erasures this compilation error is happening.

Comment: No. Type erasure has nothing to do with that error.